# Can one MudBlazor.MudDataGrid be written generically for classes of an inheritance hierarchy

Tags: inheritance, datagrid, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am looking for a way to write only one muddatagrid component for an inheritance hierarchy for example Abstract Person and Classes Staff, Customers, User ... Is this possible and how?

Comment: If you pass the parameter as a Person IEnumerable it's possible. I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkQHbcOhcjcFqcEp